# Input type text fill with a string: "Foo"<foo@foo.com> doesn't work

Tags: html, css, input

I've an input text filled with a this string `"foo foo"<foo@foo.it>` but after the insert the string look like this `"foo foo"<foo@foo.it></foo@foo.it>`. How i can resolve it? I want to show the string in first format!

Comment: Where and how do u insert it ?

Comment: You could try encoding the characters? Like so: `&quot;foo foo&quot;&lt;foo@foo.it&gt;`

Comment: I insert with javascript and the inserting is made by jquery plugin called jqgrid...

Comment: please provide snippet or code what you have tried in javascript. so that some or the other can resolve for you

Comment: when user insert the special char i convert with html entity and save on DB with this format when i recevied it i have in the data in correct format!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have something like this:

`<input type="text" value=""foo foo"<foo@foo.it>" />`

Change double quotes around the `value` attribute to single quotes. That will allow you to have double quotes inside the value of the attribute:

`<input type="text" value='"foo foo"<foo@foo.it>' />`

But now you can't have single quotes inside the value. If you need both single and double, then you will have to use a `textarea`.

Or alternatively, you can replace double quotes with `&quot;`.

Comment: Agree, or convert every `"` with `\"`

Comment: You can have both apostrophes and quotation marks in an input, just encode them right. And encode the angle brackets also: `value="&quot;foo foo&quot;&lt;foo@foo.it&gt;"`

Comment: HTML does not work like that when it comes to escaping. Try it out and you'll see :)

Comment: lol you're right, I was thinkin aj javascript... it is really friday ffs

Answer (score -1):

escape your string like this:

```
<input type="text" value="\"foo foo\"<foo@foo.it>"/>
```

Good luck